# unable to find New Layer Chooser page in GeoServer

Tags: shapefile, geoserver

I am trying to publish a shape file using GeoServer. I am not able to find the New Layer Chooser page on the website... The first picture is the website I am working on. As you could see that there is no "New Layer Chooser" page in the bar. The second picture is the instruction and it asks me to go to the "New Layer Chooser" page which doesn't seem to exist. Could someone pls tell me I can't find the New Layer Chooser page? 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are working through [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/gettingstarted/shapefile-quickstart/index.html) tutorial. Try choosing "Layers" under the "Data" heading on the left. The layer page allows you to get to the configurations for each of the layers(Step 2 under create a layer in the tutorial).

I don't have enough posts for stackoverflow to let me insert an image.

My layer page has the headings:

"New Layer"
"Add a new layer"

rather than the older "New Layer Chooser"